# Mutt add file erasing to rc command

Tags: macros, mutt

I currently have this line in my `muttrc` file to add any address to my google contacts.

```
macro index,pager a "<pipe-message>goobook add<return>" "Add sender's address to your Google contacts"
```

Problem is that when it does that I have to then go in manually and erase the goobook cache file so that it re-downloads the new address I just added.

Is there a way in that command above to add at the end of `goobook add` command a file erase command to remove the goobook cache file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out, it took a lot and a lot more of searching but I finally found it. I have to use the `<shell-escape>` command.

Very simple and the final command looks like this:

```
macro index,pager a "<pipe-message>goobook add<return><shell-escape>rm -f ~/.goobook_cache<enter>" "Add sender's address to your Google contacts"
```

It works great actually, it add's the email to my Google Contacts then erases the old cache file. So immediately after adding an address I can find it in my mutt program.